# how to install big commerce stencils in windows 10

Tags: bigcommerce

I have tried to install stencils in my windows 10 laptop. I have already install **GIT V-2.13.2 64-BIT**, **NODE.JS V-4.6.1 64-BIT**, **PYTHON V-2.7.12 64-BIT** on my laptop. but it doesn't install.

But all those versions i installed in windows 7 it works properly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, when installing the stencil please use gitbash and run all commands from gitbash in order to install on Windows 10.You will also need a C++ complier. https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/prerequisites-windows

Comment: I have also done those steps which you suggest me. but still, it's not working. what can I do?

Comment: Can you please post the errors you are getting along with the exact steps taken in your question.